# @EJB injection into standalone main client

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, code-injection

I'm trying to run this simple example which fails becose MyEJBRemote is not injected. So, it's throws NullPointerException. The server is TomEE 1.5.1.

```
public class Test
{
    @EJB
    private static MyEJBRemote ejb;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(ejb.anMethod());
    }
}
```

However, if instead of using @EJB I use the traditional JNDI lookup then the example works perfectly.

I've read similar questions but I did not understand the answers.

How can I achieve the EJB injection into an standalone main client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EJB is only supported on client side if you're using an ACC (Application Client Container),

Comment: Here is a Netbeans tutorial for [Creating and Running an Application Client on the GlassFish Server](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html), and here's a good [blog post](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2011/java-ees-buried-treasure-the-application-client-container.html) on the subject.